# after proguard public static field will remove

Tags: android, android-proguard

```
package com.hope.carwallpapers.extra;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

/**
 * Created by croma on 21-08-2016.
 */
public class StringLensFlare {
    public final static String O_1 = "{\"I\":\"p(1)\",\"ow\":768,\"oh\":491,\"data\":[{\"image\":\"two\",\"fw\":389,\"fh\":235,\"fx\":162,\"fy\":187},{\"image\":\"one\",\"fw\":389,\"fh\":235,\"fx\":461,\"fy\":187}]}";
    public final static String O_2 = "{\"I\":\"p(2)\",\"ow\":768,\"oh\":512,\"data\":[{\"image\":\"two\",\"fw\":757,\"fh\":450,\"fx\":11,\"fy\":0},{\"image\":\"two\",\"fw\":381,\"fh\":227,\"fx\":0,\"fy\":99}]}";

public static String getDeclare(int i) {

    try {
        StringLensFlare stringLensFlare = new StringLensFlare();
        Field f = stringLensFlare.getClass().getDeclaredField("O_" + i);
        f.setAccessible(true);
        return f.get(stringLensFlare).toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return "";
}
};;
```

this is my public static filed remove after proguard i have already added in

```
proguard.txt file as-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing a public static field via reflection, thus you have to instruct ProGuard to keep it:

```
-keep class StringLensFlare {
    static java.lang.String O_*;
}
```

The other rule that you mention is pretty much useless for this case and completely unrelated.